# Prove $\sqrt x$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,+\infty[$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

I have done the following:

For any given $\;\varepsilon>0\;,\;$ let $\;\delta=2\varepsilon>0\;,$

$\forall\;x,y\in[1,+\infty[\;$ with $\;|x−y|<\delta\;,$

since $\;\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\ge2\;,\;$ we get that

$\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right|=\dfrac{|x-y|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}\le\dfrac{|x-y|}{2}<\dfrac{\delta}{2}=\varepsilon\;.$

Hence, $\;\sqrt{x}\;$ is uniformly continuous on  $\;[1,+\infty[\;.$

Am I missing something? Is this proof correct?

Comment: So how do you deal with $(0,\infty)$ now ?

Comment: my bad. there was a typo in the title. It should be $(1,\infty)$

Comment: If you say so. The extension to $(0,\infty)$ was interesting.

Comment: You can actually prove via a simple trick that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean? @N.S.

Comment: Your function is uniformly continuous on $[1, \infty)$ for the same reason, and the theory tells you that it is also uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Im not getting your idea =( @N.S.

Comment: Every continuous function defined on a compact space is ...

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I see is to note that $\sqrt{x}$ is [Lipschitz](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LipschitzFunction.html) on $[1, +\infty[$.  (To show that it is Lipschitz, compute the upper bound on the absolute value of the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$.)  Lipschitz continuity implies uniform continuity.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$. It is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ because it is continuous, and because $[0,1]$ is compact. To prove uniform continuity on $[1,\infty)$, you can do this directly, as you suggest
$$
      \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y} = \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}, \\
         |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}| \le \frac{1}{2}|x-y|.
$$
Combining the results on $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$ gives you what you want.

Comment: @avs : Is $f(x)=x$ uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$? What is your reasoning?

Comment: @avs : A continuous function on a compact interval is uniformly continuous. $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Is it not?

Comment: Sorry, you are right.  What it fails to be is Lipschitz, but it is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @avs : No worries. You can check my recent points and find at least one deleted post with text in it that would make you think I belong in a home for the bewildered. It made no sense at all. And I had to think this one over quite a bit after you questioned it. Thanks for the confirmation.